# Grant access to Azure Data Lake Gen2 using a parameterized script

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-data-lake-gen2

We are trying to grant read/write access to many folders in our Azure data Lake gen 2 containers and although we can do this through the UI, it's quite tedious and has to be repeated for all environments. Has anyone used a better way using Powershell to automate or at least parameterize this process of granted access to Azure Data Lake gen 2 containers and avoid granting access manually?

Unfortunately I couldn't get this to work using the following link or other documentation as it's for Gen 1 but it's very similar to what I need to do for gen 2.
https://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2018/3/17/assigning-data-permissions-for-azure-data-lake-store-part-3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to my test, we can use the PowerShell to manage Azure Data Lake Gen2 permissions.  For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-powershell#manage-access-permissions)

1. Install the required module

```
install-Module PowerShellGet –Repository PSGallery –Force
install-Module Az.Storage -Repository PSGallery -RequiredVersion 1.9.1-preview –AllowPrerelease –AllowClobber –Force
```

> Besides, please note that if you want to install the module, you need to meet some conditions
>
> - .NET Framework is `4.7.2` or greater installed
> - PowerShell is `5.1` or higher

2. Script

```
Connect-AzAccount

$groupName=""
$accountName=""
$account= Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $groupName -Name $accountName
$ctx = $account.Context

$filesystemName = "test"
$dirname="template/"
$Id = "<the Object ID of user, group or service principal>"
$dir=Get-AzDataLakeGen2Item -Context $ctx -FileSystem $filesystemName -Path $dirname
$acl = New-AzDataLakeGen2ItemAclObject -AccessControlType user -EntityId $id -Permission "rw-" -InputObject $dir.ACL
Update-AzDataLakeGen2Item -Context $ctx -FileSystem $filesystemName -Path $dirname -Acl $acl
$dir=Get-AzDataLakeGen2Item -Context $ctx -FileSystem $filesystemName -Path $dirname
$dir.ACL
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you Jim Xu. That's very helpful, I tested that and it works for my test data lake.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jim Xu for providing the script above. I'm just complementing the code with the following items :

- Get all folders from the container
- Assign ACL for all folders
- Propagate ACL to all subfolders

```
$groupName="resource group name"
$accountName="storage account name"
$account= Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $groupName -Name $accountName
$ctx = $account.Context

$filesystemName = "container name"
$Id = (Get-AzADGroup -DisplayName '<type user / group name here>').Id
$items = Get-AzDataLakeGen2ChildItem -Context $ctx -FileSystem $filesystemName

foreach ( $item in $items) {
    
    $dir = Get-AzDataLakeGen2Item -Context $ctx -FileSystem $filesystemName -Path "$($item.Path)/"
    $acl = New-AzDataLakeGen2ItemAclObject -AccessControlType group -EntityId $id -Permission "rwx" -InputObject $dir.ACL -DefaultScope
     
    # Update ACL on blob item
    Update-AzDataLakeGen2Item -Context $ctx -FileSystem $filesystemName -Path "$($item.Path)/" -Acl $acl
    
    # Propagate ACL to child blob items
    Set-AzDataLakeGen2AclRecursive -Context $ctx -FileSystem $filesystemName -Path "$($item.Path)/" -Acl $acl
}
```